# How to insert a RecordSet to Route53 in another AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

My team is developing a product that launches new EC2 instances with some software in it, and we run a small piece of python code upon the instance's boot up process to register it in our Route53 DNS. The EC2 instances and our Route53 are in different AWS accounts.

While this python code works beautifully, it is my task now to rewrite this piece of software in golang.

I have already created an IAM Role in the Route53's account with the proper policy, and it works fine. I've also allowed it to be invoked by the other AWS account, and it also works nicely. The python code is able to assume-role using this IAM Role and so create a new RecordSet in Route53. However, when I try to perform this using my golang code, I get...

`AccessDenied: Access denied
    status code: 403, request id: xxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy-zzzzzzzz`

This is as far as I can go with my understanding of IAM:

```
(...)

sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
        svc := sts.New(sess)
        input := &sts.AssumeRoleInput{
            DurationSeconds: aws.Int64(900),
            ExternalId:      aws.String("register-dns"),
            RoleArn:         aws.String(roleARN),
            RoleSessionName: aws.String(roleSessionName),
        }
        result, err := svc.AssumeRole(input)
        check(err)

        creds := stscreds.NewCredentials(sess, roleARN)
        service := route53.New(sess, &aws.Config{Credentials: creds})
        inputs := &route53.ChangeResourceRecordSetsInput{
            ChangeBatch: &route53.ChangeBatch{
                Changes: []*route53.Change{
                    {
                        Action: aws.String("UPSERT"),
                        ResourceRecordSet: &route53.ResourceRecordSet{
                            Name: aws.String(instanceName + ".mycompany.com"),
                            ResourceRecords: []*route53.ResourceRecord{
                                {
                                    Value: aws.String(hostIP),
                                },
                            },
                            TTL:  aws.Int64(60),
                            Type: aws.String("A"),
                        },
                    },
                },
                Comment: aws.String(instanceName),
            },
            HostedZoneId: aws.String(hostedZoneID),
        }

        resultR53, err := service.ChangeResourceRecordSets(inputs)

(...)
```

At this point I was expecting my code to assume IAM Role `roleARN` and create a RecordSet in Route53 with it. But instead, I've been getting Access Denied constantly.

Is this the right procedure to access some AWS resource in a different AWS account?

Thanks!

What I've used as base:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sts/#STS.AssumeRole

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/stscreds

Comment: Can you show the policy of the role that is being assumed?

Comment: Possible red flag, security vulnerability: you are planning to put code in someone else's hands that has permission manipulate entries in *your* account's hosted zone?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot we do this regularly; good practice to separate concerns in to different accounts.

Comment: @hephalump I would agree, but that's not really the same thing as what I see contemplated here.  OP describes a "product" (implying something released to and run under control of a third party) that registers itself in "our" (not the third party's) DNS.  It's a solid recipe for (sub)domain hijacking, the way I read it, hence the red flag.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you're right that if they gave code to a third party that manages their zone then that is potentially very dangerous. However, I disagree with your position that a "product implies something released to and run under control of a third party". In a SaaS environment, you have a product that the user uses, but they never have access to the code... Maybe the OP can give us some insight in this regards so can help him more :)

Comment: No, my company is the owner of both AWS accounts, so nothing is run in a third-party account. It's just that the instances are launched in one account, and our domain is registered in a different account, again, owned by my company. But I appreciate your concern!

Comment: @hephalump It is a role with Amazon's AmazonRoute53FullAccess policy, and I added my company's other account in this role's Trusted Entities